# Homeomorphism $\mathbb{B}^n \to \mathbb{B}^n$ that is not a diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-functions, diffeomorphism

I am trying to prove that for any $s > 0, F_s(x) = |x|^{s-1}x$ defines a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{B}^n$ to itself, which is a diffeomorphism iff $s = 1$.

My attempt so far:
Let $F_s(x) = |x|^{s-1}x = |x|^s \widehat{x}$, where $\widehat{x} = \frac{x}{|x|}$ is the normalisation of $x$. Hence, we see that $|F_s(x)| < 1$ if $|x| < 1$, and thus that $F_s(\mathbb{B}^n) \subset \mathbb{B}^n$. Also, for $s,t > 0$  we see that
$$
F_t \circ F_s (x) = F_t(|x|^s \widehat{x}) = ||x|^s \widehat{x}|^t \widehat{|x|^s \widehat{x}} = |x|^{st} \underbrace{|\widehat{x}|^t}_{=1} \widehat{|x|^s \widehat{x}} = |x|^{st} \widehat{x} = F_{st}(x). 
$$
In particular, this gives that $F_{1/s} \circ F_{s} = F_s \circ F_{1/s} = F_1 = id_{\mathbb{B}^n}$. So $F_s$ is a bijection. It is a homeomorphism because $F_s$ is a composition and quotient of the continuous maps $|\cdot|$ and $(\cdot)^s$ for $x \neq 0$. For $x = 0$ we see that $F_s(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, so it is also continuous in $x =0$. Finally, for $s = 1$ we have the identity map, which is a diffeomorphism. For $s < 1$, then $F_s(x) = |x|^{s-1}x = \frac{x}{|x|^{1-s}}$, I suspect that this is not differentiable in the origin, but I don't know how to show this, that's where I am stuck. For $s > 1$, then the inverse $F_{1/s}$ is not smooth since $\frac{1}{s} < 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remark that if $F_s$ is a diffeo, then its differential is invertible at any point by the chain rule:
$$F^{-1}\circ F=\mathrm{id}\implies\forall x,D(F^{-1})_{F(x)}\circ DF_x=\mathrm{id}.$$
Thus it has trivial kernel at all points of $\mathbb{B}^n$.

Now take the smooth curve $\gamma:(-1,1)\to\mathbb{B}^n$ defined by $\gamma(t)=(t,0,\dots,0)$. You can check that for $t>0$, $(F_s\circ \gamma)(t)=(t^s,0,\dots,0)$. If $F_s$ was smooth, then $F_s\circ\gamma$ would also be by composition: for $s<1$, this is not the case. Now, for $s>1$, note that by the chain rule

$$(DF_s)_0((1,0,\dots,0))=(DF_s)_{\gamma(0)}(\gamma'(0))=(F_s\circ\gamma)'(0)=(st^{s-1},0,\dots,0)|_{t=0}=0,$$
and this contradicts the triviality of the kernel of $(DF_s)_0$.

You can also conclude for $s>1$ as you did in the post, namely showing that $F_s$ is not a diffeo since $(F_s)^{-1}=F_{\frac{1}{s}}$ is not differentiable at $0$ since$\frac{1}{s}<1$ and this case has already been dealed with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, if I understand it correctly, for $s < 1$ we can use the argument about the fact that $F_s \circ \gamma$ is not smooth. Then for $s > 1$ we can use that $F_s^{-1} = F_{\frac{1}{s}}$ is not smooth. Hence, then we would not need the argument about the differential? 
Also, to see that $f(t) = t^s$ is not smooth for $0 < s < 1$, is this because $f'(t) = st^{s-1} = \frac{s}{t^{1-s}} \to \infty$ as $t \to 0$. So the derivative exists but is not continuous at $0$?

Comment: Yes, we would not need it there. It is the same reasonning when you want to show that $x\mapsto x^3$ is not a diffeomorphism: either show that its inverse is not smooth (because there is a point $x_0$ where $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{x_0}}{x-x_0}$ does not exist - including cases where it is $\pm\infty$), or you show that its derivative has a vanishing point, which is excluded since by the chain rule $f'(x)\cdot (f^{-1})'(f(x))=1$. Also yes for your second question.